# How do I install mysql on cygwin?

Tags: mysql, cygwin

I've been trying to install mysql on my cygwin. There isn't a package for this on the repo, so I figured I'll compile one, but I can't figure out what package I need to use, nor which options should I send to ./configure

any tips?

Comment: Out of curiosity: why do you want to do that? There are native packages for Windows

Comment: I would recommend using xampp http://www.apachefriends.org/en/xampp.html which has everything you need in one little package.

Comment: I'm running my ruby from my cygwin, due to some gem having issues with win environment. The mysql gem requires that I have mysql on my machine (cygwin in this case)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name is there a way to install those same native packages in cygwin path? For example (This is assumed code) 'ln -s /cygdrive/c/msql/msql.exe mysql

Comment: I think I answered my own question.: http://stackoverflow.com/q/329866/635160

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Cygwin Ports project has mysql packages. See http://sourceware.org/cygwinports.

Answer (score 16):

Use apt-cyg, you just need the command:

```
apt-cyg install mysql
```

http://code.google.com/p/apt-cyg/

Comment: If i have already installed xampp in my windows machine, will this command mess with my current mysql installation as well as all the databases?

Comment: You made my day! Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Fistly ,try to download https://github.com/transcode-open/apt-cyg
，and then execute the following command 'apt-cyg install mysql' . 
It's worked!

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't matter much which version you need to use.  Just download the generic linux source from [here](http://www.mysql.com/downloads/mirror.php?id=399302).  **Edit:** URL is out of date.  [Download generic linux source here](https://downloads.mysql.com/archives/community/).

I know there used to be a readline bug in cygwin but you should be able to get past that with this in your configure:

```
./configure --without-readline CFLAGS=-O2
```

Might be worth it to try without the flags first, just make sure you run `make distclean` if you try multiple configures.

Otherwise here's are the commands to get you going:

```
tar xzvf mysql-5.5.8.tar.gz
cd mysql-5.0.57
./configure
make
make install
```

You should be good to go from there.

Comment: I have looked at this package. it has no configure file, and trying to use the configure.cmake file did not work

Comment: Ok. found instruction in the file. 
Should have use "cmake ." (after downloading the package). Now we'll see if this sticks

Comment: How did you get past the error: conflicting types for 'dtoa'?  I am getting this error trying to compile 5.5.8 or 5.5.20.  http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=62627