# How Netbeans' terminal (cygwin) can be used as a CLI to connect to MySQL

Tags: mysql, command-line, terminal, cygwin, netbeans-7

I am using Netbeans IDE v7.2 on Windows 7 & also using its `terminal` feature for some other stuff (like mkdir, touch, tar, etc.).

Now I also want to use the terminal to connect to `MySQL` via a command line interface (`CLI`).
Currently I have to use command prompt. I want to do all things through the IDE only.

I Googled about it but did not get any success, so I want someone to help me on this.

1. Which application do I have to download to support terminal (`Cygwin`) for MySQL CLI (it says:

   > Command does not exist
2. After download how to configure and connect it with my existing MySQL Database (XAMPP)

Thanks for you help!

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to run the Cygwin setup program, and install the mysql libraries. [See this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4806846/how-do-i-install-mysql-on-cygwin).

Once that's installed an you no longer get `Command does not exist` when running `mysql` in the terminal, you can connect using the commands here: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mysql.html

Answer (score 1):

Did you have set the folowing in your environment variables? :

**Uservariabel:**

Path C:\Windows\System32

**Systemvariabel:**

Path C:\Windows\System32

If not? Try it. And after you have set that, restart your Netbeans so that it will have effect.