# Opening PostgreSQL in Cygwin and MINTTY

Tags: cygwin, mintty

I can't seem to open the interactive mode of PSQL using MINTTY or using the default Cygwin terminal, it just stalls under the command `psql databasename` and does nothing. The only way to get it to respond is to ctrl+C out of it. It works fine in Command Prompt.

I know that for Python you need to enter the -i argument - is there a similar trick for Cygwin?

Comment: what command are you using?  i would expect `mintty -e psql databasename -` to work.

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't work. Also, I am trying to switch to using mintty as my default terminal, so I would be calling `psql databasename` in MINTTY already.

Answer (score 2):

I'm having the same problem. For some reason

```
psql -l -h localhost -U postgres
```

returns a listing of dataabases, but any other variation on psql just hangs, silently.

---

Edit: I found the answer here: [how to set up the psql command in cygwin?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14489594/how-to-set-up-the-psql-command-in-cygwin)

> Windows psql uses Windows console functions; Cygwin runs best in a
>   terminal like Console2, which doesn't support Windows console API. So
>   psql doesn't work well with Cygwin at all. What's needed is a Cygwin
>   build of client tools like psql

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar issue with Mercurial (hg)+OpenSSH, Python and MinTTY, but under MSYS instead of CygWin. I had this exact same problem with `mysql` as well.  Nonetheless, as far as I can tell, both this and my issue were caused by MinTTY not being to handle applications that uses the native Windows console functions.

I solved my issue by following the solution found in comment 64 of https://code.google.com/p/mintty/issues/detail?id=56#c64

With the winpty (https://github.com/rprichard/winpty) project compiled and installed in my path, I was able to run **native** Python (in interactive mode), Mercurial and MySQL from the MinTTY shell without special builds or switches (such as `python -i`).  All I need was to append `console.exe` or `console` before the `python` or `hg` command.  For convenience, I added aliases such as `alias hg="console.exe hg"` so I can use the same commands whether I'm in a Linux shell or a Windows MinTTY bash shell.