# Generating SSL keys for MySQL command-line client encrypted connection

Tags: java, mysql, amazon-web-services, ssl, ssh-keys

I have started a project using MySQL in the cloud and I need to set up an SSL connection to it for the MySQL command line client.

I received the `ca.pem` file from the MySQL server which has a ton of certificates in there.

I already sorted out the SSL connection in MySQL Workbench and in Java, after a certain amount of trying different things. I've all the certificates now in my Java installation's cacerts trust store, and I've configured Java and Workbench to find my public / private SSL keys in my client.jks store.

None of that though helps with the command line MySQL client. According to the MySQL docs [Configuring MySQL to use Secure Connections](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/using-secure-connections.html), this is the way to launch it:

```
mysql --ssl-ca=ca.pem \
   --ssl-cert=client-cert.pem \
   --ssl-key=client-key.pem
```

and these params can be put in `my.cnf` to make the command line easier.

And this told me some of what I needed to know: [MySQL on Amazon RDS](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/CHAP_MySQL.html#MySQL.Concepts.SSLSupport) i.e. how to point `mysql` on the command line to the server certificate. That was easy, considering the Java procedure required me to import the whole lot into the Java certificate store using a command line tool that only reads the first certificate and silently ignores the remainder.

So after all faff with Java, and from the beginning having a public/private key pair for `ssh`, it occurred to me it would be sensible to keep all my keys together and in fact even re-use the same key to create the other formats I need.

According to [Converting a Java Keystore into PEM Format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/652916/converting-a-java-keystore-into-pem-format) I should be able to do that, or maybe I should instead use the `SSH` keys? They all share the same Country/State/Locality/Org/Unit/Name/Email.

The MySQL docs [Creating SSL Certificates and Keys Using OpenSSL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/creating-ssl-files-using-openssl.html) says I need to do this:

```
openssl req -newkey rsa:2048 -days 3600 \
     -nodes -keyout client-key.pem -out client-req.pem
openssl rsa -in client-key.pem -out client-key.pem
openssl x509 -req -in client-req.pem -days 3600 \
     -CA ca.pem -CAkey ca-key.pem -set_serial 01 -out client-cert.pem
openssl verify -CAfile ca.pem server-cert.pem client-cert.pem
```

This is problematic because I didn't generate the AWS certificates and I only got one pem file from there. Maybe the AWS ca.pem and server-cert.pem are both in the one pem file - guess I could check but I'll have to go and dig out the info about which CA signing authority they use so I could recognise the CA cert. And I guess the 'server-cert' is the public key from the actual host I've got.

But it doesn't work, I get the following error:

```
$ openssl.exe x509 -req -in client-req.pem -days 3600 
        -CA rds-combined-ca-bundle.pem -CAkey rds-combined-ca-bundle.pem 
        -set_serial 01 -out client-cert.pem
Signature ok
subject=/C=UK/ST=LN/L=LN/O=X/OU=XYZ/CN=xyz/emailAddress=adam@me.com
Getting CA Private Key
unable to load CA Private Key
4294956672:error:0906D06C:PEM routines:PEM_read_bio:no start 
        line:pem_lib.c:707:Expecting: ANY PRIVATE KEY
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the SSL certificates are a red herring. You don't need them. All you need is this:

```
mysql -h myinstance.c9akciq32.rds-us-east-1.amazonaws.com
    --ssl-ca=[full path]rds-combined-ca-bundle.pem --ssl-verify-server-cert
```

It's Cygwin and the standard Windows MySQL client don't play well together, hence the hanging when trying to start:  [connecting to mysql from cygwin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/329866/connecting-to-mysql-from-cygwin)